# Python - Keeping string intact while extending other string

Tags: python, string, extend

My Code is splitting up a file line by line into strings and extends them to a list.

I noticed that for cases where **only one** string is extended, the result will split up that string and extend it letter by letter to the empty list. If I delete [-1] the string remains intact, but the other strings will be extended aswell.

How can I prevent that string from being split up when extending it to the empty list?

```
searchstring = "abc dfe ghi"     #resembles a searchline from a file
text = searchstring.split()          #note: same thing happens if i add [-1] here
list1.extend(text[-1])           #I only want the last element of the string
```

So either the output is:

```
print list1
[abc, dfe, ghi]
```

or

```
print list1
[g, h, i]
```

but I need it this way

```
print list1
[ghi]             #one entry for each line in the file
```

Comment: I have not understood what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? Are your `abc`, `dfe`, `ghi` supposed to be string literals? It will be easier to help you if you could provide exact code which fully replicates your problem as well as the intended output.

Comment: @AlexAlifimoff: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256331/2988730

Comment: just edited it a bit

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I can't cast close votes so I do what is within my abilities to help as best as possible.

Comment: @AlexAlifimoff. Thanks. I'm glad you did that and I'm glad OP listened. I have now retracted my close vote thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.extend` accepts an iterable.

So when you pass it a string (`ghi`) it uses it like a list, extending list with chars from that string.

You may want to put that string to a list or use `list.append`.

Comment: solved: list.append works. I already used it somewhere else in the code, but sometimes you just dont find the obvious solution. Thanks! (stackoverflow wont let me mark your answear as solution for the next 5 min)